# Droid camera screen upside down display

Tags: android

I have this App, which will help tune camera to to zoom in or zoom out and adjust contrast and stuff, but the image that camera focuses on is displayed with swapped vertical and horizontal axis. So when I run this app and focus on vertical text it is displayed as portrait and vice versa. It is not problem with the way we hold camera but the way text is displayed